# nao camera wrapper node

Tags: ros, naoqi, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to get a ROS node running, which should publish the images grabbed by the cameras of the Nao robot (latest generation, H25 with Intel ATOM CPU). Therefore I'm using the Aldebaran C++ API.

First, I tried to use the NAO-ROS camera driver from Brown Uni, but it didn't work in my case either. This link reports the problem:
http://answers.ros.org/question/1864/nao-teleop-and-camera-feed

So when writing an own wrapper node for the cameras, I tried to integrate the necessary Aldebaran API functions according to Aldebaran's API docu. The node should work remotely, so it is *not* loaded onto the robot.
My wrapper node compiles, but it crashes with segmentation fault immadiately at run time.
I'm using image_transport of ROS, and I'm sure the ROS part of the code works fine as I used the concept with a simple webcam before without problems. However, I think the problem lies within the Aldebaran API and libraries. As soon as they are included, the node still compiles, but crashes at run time.

Has anyone a solution or useful hints to this problem?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33090/nao-camera-wrapper-node/) by [_phdstudent](https://answers.ros.org/users/2292/_phdstudent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just wrote a small ROS python wrapper for Nao's camera. You can find it in our nao_driver package (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao_driver).

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without knowing what your code looks like, my first guess would be that you tried to link ROS and Aldebaran's naoqi into the same binary. naoqi is linked to a specific boost version, included in the naoqi SDK. ROS links (probably) to another boost version in /usr/lib/. One solution would be to compile ROS from source and let it link to the boost version included in the naoqi SDK. The easiest solution would be to use python.

---

Originally posted by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) with karma: 290 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1